# Spark Streaming: schema mismatch using MicroBatchReader with columns pruning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a custom Spark streaming source. I want to support columns pruning.
I cannot share the full code, anyway I did something like this:

```
class MyMicroBatchReader(...) extends MicroBatchReader with SupportsPushDownRequiredColumns {

  var schema: StructType = createSchema()

  def readSchema(): StructType = schema

  def pruneColumns(requiredSchema: StructType): Unit = {
    schema = requiredSchema
  }

  ...

}
```

And I'm creating the batches rows using the schema: I've already checked that in the rows that I return there are only the values of the requested columns.

However, if I run a streaming query selecting some columns, the job fails. For example, running

```
spark.readStream().format("mysource").load().select("Id").writeStream().format("console").start()
```

I obtain the following exception:

```
18/06/29 15:50:01 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 59c13195-9d63-42c9-8f92-eb9d67e8b26c, runId = 72124019-1ab3-48a9-9503-0cf1c7d26fb9] terminated with error
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Invalid batch: fieldA#0,fieldB#1,fieldC,Id#3,fieldD#4,fieldE#5 != Id#52
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:416)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Can you please help me understanding what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the version of Spark? Can you `explain(true)` the streaming dataset, i.e. `spark.readStream().format("mysource").load().select("Id").explain(true)`?

Comment: Happens here as well, for some reason only in second batch iteration -

explain command:

sparkSession.readStream.format(myV2Source).load().select("c1").explain(true)
results:

Comment: == Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias('c1, None)]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- StreamingRelationV2 com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource@11987483, com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource, Map(), [c1#452, c2#453L, c3#454,  ... 26 more fields]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
c1: string
Project [c1#452]
+- StreamingRelationV2 com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource@11987483, com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource, Map(), [c1#452, c2#453L, c3#454, ... 26 more fields]

Comment: == Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [c1#452]
+- StreamingRelationV2 com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource@11987483, com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource, Map(), [c1#452, c2#453L, c3#454, ... 26 more fields]

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [c1#452]
+- StreamingRelation com.mycompany.v2.MyDefaultSource, [c1#452, c2#453L, c3#454, ... 26 more fields]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting schema to be the full scheme after every microbatch commit:

```
class MyMicroBatchReader(...) extends MicroBatchReader with SupportsPushDownRequiredColumns {

  var fullSchema: StructType = createSchema()
  var schema: StructType = fullSchema

  def readSchema(): StructType = schema

  def pruneColumns(requiredSchema: StructType): Unit = {
    schema = requiredSchema
  }

  def commit (end: OffsetV2): Unit = {  
    ...
    schema = fullSchema
  }

}
```